I Can't Use Strapi Session (Koa)
I'm trying use session in strapi. But i can't use save or use session.
import { Strapi } from '@strapi/strapi'

export default ({ strapi }: { strapi: Strapi }) => ({
    search: {
        resolve: async (obj, { name }, context) => {
            console.log(context.session, context.state.user)
            context.session = context.state.user // <---
            return await strapi.service('api::printful.product').search({ name })
        }
    }
})

I tried use like this session. But when send second request context.session still undefinied.
And my config/middleware.ts file look like this.
export default ({ env }) => ({
    settings: {
        session: {
            enabled: true,
            client: 'cookie',
            key: 'strapi.sid',
            prefix: 'strapi:sess:',
            secretKeys: env.array('APP_KEYS'),
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 24 hours
            overwrite: true,
            signed: false,
            rolling: false
        },
        // cookieParser: {
        //     enabled: true
        // }
    }
})

Strapi Version : 4.21.0
Node Version : 18.20.2
What am I doing wrong?

When i set context.session in GQL resolvers, context.session not setting. Because in resolver, not a real controller. Because context object is a copy. When i set context.session in controller its working!
